# Specify the point on the page where a paragraph ends

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, paragraphs

Is there any way to control the point on the page where a paragraph ends?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I've marked with a red arrow the point where the paragraph ends. 
[image]

Say, for some reason, I wanted to force the paragraph to end at specific point, like at the centre of the page as shown in the example below. Is this possible?
[image]

As an additional question, is it possible to specify a region where the paragraph can end? And let the TeX line-breaking algorithm work out how best to accommodate that?
[image]

Comment: Very strange request :)

Comment: Yes I know it's better not to play with these sort of things and just let the algorithm work out the best text/line spacing. But just curious to see if this kind of control is possible. I realise it will sacrifice optimal spacing between the words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image: mwe]

The length that you are searching is `\parfillskip` but change the default length, specially when set to `0pt` can produce often a very bad spacing in the last line, so you may want play also with a generous  `\emergencystretch` to avoid that (and also with the `microtype` options, since you are already using this package). However, with long paragraphs as `\blindtext` the `\emergencystretch` changes seem to do nothing, but play  with narrow texts, big fonts or short paragraphs to see the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.5\textwidth}
\blindtext

\setlength{\parfillskip}{.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0pt}
\blindtext

\setlength{\parfillskip}{.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0pt}
 Bblablablabla  blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla
blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla

\setlength{\parfillskip}{.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.5\textwidth}
 Bblablablabla  blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla
blablablabla blablablabla blablablabla

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have several questions about paragraphs, so I have several pointers for you regarding articles I wrote for TUGboat. Check out [Paragraphs](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf), [More Paragraphs](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-2/tb92glister.pdf) and the latest, if you are a TUG member, [Paragraph endings](https://tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120glister.pdf). I think that if you read the articles you will find answers to your, and many other, quaestions.