# Right-justify last line of paragraph

Tags: environments, paragraphs

I am looking for a neat way of right-justifying the last line of a LaTeX paragraph. This is useful when I want to continue a paragraph from a minipage to main text.

Here's one way. Let #text be the text of the last line of the paragraph. In its place code `\makebox[\textwidth][s]{#text}`.

However, this is clumsy because it requires you to do an initial pass to see what LaTeX creates as the last line.

Comment: `\parfillskip=0pt` before the last paragraph in the `minipage`. But it could make for very bad typesetting.

Comment: [Specify the point on the page where a paragraph ends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430511/specify-the-point-on-the-page-where-a-paragraph-ends)